# How to control property enumeration (for...in) with Proxy objects?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I'm wrapping an object in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and then iterate through it. How can I control the keys it iterates through?

The proxy works if I don't override the keys:

```js
var obj = {"hello": "world"}
var proxy = new Proxy(obj, {})
for (var key in proxy){
    console.log(key)
}
// logs "Hello"
```

However, nothing is logged if I change the keys in the `ownKeys` handler.

```js
var obj = {"hello": "world"}
var proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    ownKeys: function(){
        return ["a", "b"]
    }
})
for (var key in proxy){
    console.log(key)
}
// Logs nothing
```

If I return `"hello"` as part of the `ownKeys` only `"hello"` is logged.

Apparently there was an [`enumerate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/enumerate) trap in ES6, but it has been removed from ES7.

Is it still possible to control the `for...in` loop with a Proxy? Why was `enumerate` removed from the spec?

Comment: you need to implement getOwnPropertyDescriptor proxy trap too, to set them enumerable!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to do this anymore.

As Brian Terlson (the editor of the EcmaScript Specification) wrote:

> issue with proxy enumerate trap and for-in, where iimplementations are
>   prevented from pre-populating the list of keys in the object, because
>   the iterator causes observable affects. Which means the iterate must
>   be pulled for every iteration. Last meeting we thought it would be ok
>   if the enumerate trap exhausts the iterator, we thought that would
>   solve the problem. The issue was, now their is an observable
>   difference between an object and proxy of that object, mainly due to
>   delete.

(Source: https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2016-01/2016-01-28.md#5xix-proxy-enumerate---revisit-decision-to-exhaust-iterator via https://ecmascript-daily.github.io/2016/02/10/why-remove-enumerate-and-reflect-enumerate)

So it was removed due to technical challenges that could not be solved in a satisfactory manner.

***has* proxy trap**

The `in` operator as such can still be captured using the [`has` proxy trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/has):

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
  has: function(target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'a') { return true; }
    return false;
  }
});
'a' in p; // true
'b' in p; // false
```

**Alternative**

As `for (let key in proxy)` loops are more of a legacy feature these days, you could use one of the following with the `ownKeys` proxy trap:

- `Object.keys()` (own enumerable properties only)
- `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` (own properties)
- `Reflect.ownKeys()` (own properties and Symbols)

[image]
(Source: https://twitter.com/nilssolanki/status/659839340592422912)

(but you probably already knew that, seeing that you are working with proxies in the first place)

Comment: Thanks Nils, awesome answer. I happen to be in an environment where I can use Babel to modify the code before execution, so I can add my custom logic that way.

Comment: *I can use Babel to modify the code before execution, so I can add my custom logic that way.* I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Basically I can transform the code before it runs, so I can either replace the `for...in` loop with something else, or I can update it to contain my logic. It's not something you can do in most production situations, but I'm already running Babel on the code I'm working with, so it's not a problem.

Comment: for (key in proxy) can be implemented. You need to implement ownKeys proxy trap as Nils said, and maybe you need to implement getOwnPropertyDescriptor proxy trap too to set them enumerable!

Comment: The [TC39 meeting minutes note can now be found here](https://github.com/rwaldron/tc39-notes/blob/master/es7/2016-01/jan-28.md#5xix-proxy-enumerate---revisit-decision-to-exhaust-iterator).

Comment: @nils, would it be possible for you to mention adding `ownKeys` and `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` handlers at the top of your answer? I know personally when I googled, I found this post, and after only reading the first two paragraphs of your answer I thought overriding `for...in` iteration was not possible. Only later did when I read the comments did I find out it was possible, and exactly how to do it.

Comment: @yeerk that's why anyone can edit. Feel free to edit if you're sure of what you write.

Answer (score 9):

user2106769 gave the solution as a comment, but for anyone else like me who didn't see their comment, you can override `for..in` iteration with `ownKeys` and `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```js
var obj = { "hello": "world" };
var proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    ownKeys() {
        return ["a", "b"];
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) {
        return { enumerable: true, configurable: true, value: proxy[key] };
    }
});
for (var key in proxy) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

**Edit**: As Pärt Johanson mentioned, for correctness, "value" should be returned by getOwnPropertyDescriptor. `proxy[key]` ensures if a get handler is added later (or already exists), it will be called.

Keep in mind, this will result in a get access for each key, every time the keys are iterated over. If your get handler is relatively expensive, your code can become twice as slow (if you are iterating over each value as well), or 'infinitely' slower (if you are iterating only to access the keys, and don't even want the value).

Comment: "*for correctness, "value" should be returned by getOwnPropertyDescriptor.*" - yes, but your code is not doing that (correctly)

Comment: @Bergi, good point, the value is now correctly set to `proxy[key]` (instead of `this[key]`).

Comment: Didn't you mean `target[key]`?

Comment: @Bergi, in this specific case `target[key]` gives the same result, but if the get handler is overridden proxy[key] will make sure that handler is called as well. Because I'm almost always overriding the get handler when I write a proxy, I prefer to use `proxy[key]`.

Answer (score 6):

User user2106769 suggestion and yeerk's answer of overriding the getOwnPropertyDescriptor to allow enumeration of Proxy attributes has a flaw that one should be aware of when using it, it doesn't set the value attribute when trapping getOwnPropertyDescriptor, thus some other code that depends on that behavior will not function correctly.

The code demonstrating the flaw and the solution to it is below:

```js
var obj = { "hello": "world" };
var flawedProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    ownKeys: function() {
        return ["a", "b"];
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(target, key) {
         return { enumerable: true, configurable: true };
    }
});

var goodProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, key) {
      // modify something here if you want to
      return target[key];
    },
    ownKeys: function() {
        return ["a", "b"];
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: function(target, key) {
         return { value: this.get(target, key), enumerable: true, configurable: true };
    }
});

// value is accessible, getOwnPropertyDescriptor not trapped
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'hello').value);

// value is undefined, getOwnPropertyDescriptor not trapped correctly
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(flawedProxy, 'hello').value);

// value is accessible, getOwnPropertyDescriptor trapped correctly
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(goodProxy, 'hello').value);
```

Comment: Isn't that a bug of how the trap works? It seems like .value should be set..

Comment: This still seems overly simplified compared to what would be needed in production. Woudn't enumerable and configurable need to be false in some circumstances, and just overriding the whole object to be true may cause issues?

Comment: Instead of calling `this.get` to get the value, better use `Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, so that it will also work with getters/setters

Comment: @Bergi, I may be wrong here, but I believe `proxy[key]` is the best way to access the value IF you are 100% certain the `proxy` variable will not be reassigned. I have personally found that accessing the `proxy` object helps avoid forgetting to call the appropriate `Reflect` functions.

Comment: @yeerk No, I meant `return { ...Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) ?? {value: undefined}, enumerable: true, configurable: true }` so that it can also return accessor descriptors